# standalone package, with its subpreambles option, ignores content of a standalone input file if it contains accents in glossary entry

Tags: glossaries, accents, standalone

The following MWE works like a charm:

```
% test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{glossaries}
%
\begin{filecontents}{stdalone}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newglossaryentry{cafe}
{
    name={cafe},
    % name={café},
    description={beverage that makes you sleep if you don't drink it}
}
\begin{document}
Foo.
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
%
\begin{document}
\input{stdalone}
\end{document}
```

But, as soon as `name={cafe}` is replaced by some string containing accents, e.g. `name={café}`, the standalone input file's content is ignored with the following warning:

```
Package standalone Warning: Sub-preamble of file 'stdalone.tex' has changed.
Content will be ignored. Please rerun LaTeX! on input line 14.
```

The sub-preamble of file `stdalone.tex` is stored in the file `test.sta` and, AFAICS, it doesn't change between compilations (from the 2<sup>nd</sup> one).

Do you see what's going on?

Comment: It works if you add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to the main file, so it is probably a catcode issue.

Comment: Note that `glossaries` is not fully functional if entries are defined after `\begin{document}` and it is strongly recommended that all entries be defined in the preamble (or in files loaded there etc.). Also `glossaries` provides its own method for loading files of entries and it would almost certainly be better to make use of that facility.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer In fact, I simplified too much my real use case for the MWE above: in my real use case, both the `standalone` and the `inputenc` packages are loaded in the main but through a personal class, and the trouble still occurs. But your comment made me realize the former was loaded before the latter, which wasn't in any case a good idea. Interchanging the order solved this issue :)

Comment: @cfr You're right but in my MWE, all the entries are defined in the preamble (the `.sta` file is read before `\begin{document}`).

Comment: The file is written before `\begin{document}` but it is not `\input` until afterwards. So the entry is defined in the body of the document, I think. Although perhaps `standalone` is smart enough to put the entries with the list of packages from the sub-preambles it collects. I don't know it well enough to say how it handles the contents of sub-preambles.

Comment: @cfr The `.sta` contains all is in the preamble of the subfile(s), for instance the `\usepackage` and the `\newglossaryentry` commands. If it would not be input in the preamble of the main file; compilations would fail because of the `\usepackage` commands.

Comment: I knew it did that for `\usepackage`. I didn't know if it collected those of it it merged the entire contents of the sub-preambles, so thanks for the info.

Comment: @cfr That depends whether the option `subpreambles` is used or not (and subsequent other options `sort`, `print`, etc.).

Comment: If @UlrikeFischer 's comment solved the problem, would you like her to write an answer so you can accept it? Otherwise, perhaps you could edit your question to clarify the remaining issue?

Comment: @cfr I had the intention to invite her to do so but I forgot it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If you'd transform your comment into an answer, I could accept it.