# standalone wrongly claims sub-preamble of a subfile changed

Tags: standalone, preamble, subfiles, babel-french

(Maybe related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303258/18401).)

Each `pdflatex` compilation of the following MCE:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{subfile.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\mycolon{:}
\begin{document}
Foo.
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\input{subfile.tex}
\end{document}
```

leads to:

> Package standalone Warning: Sub-preamble of file 'subfile.tex' has changed. Content will be ignored. Please rerun LaTeX! on input line 7.

But the sub-preamble of file 'subfile.tex' obviously didn't change. This trouble probably has to do:

- with `\newcommand\mycolon{:}` in the preamble of the sub file, since the warning is not emitted anymore if it is moved to the document body,
- with `babel-french`, since the warning is not emitted anymore if the `french` option in the main file is removed; and this has probably to do with the colon (`:`) made active by `babel-french` at the beginning of the document.

Even if I could work around by moving `\newcommand\mycolon{:}` to the document body, do you understand what's going on and how to get the whole working with both:

- `\newcommand\mycolon{:}` in the preamble,
- `babel-french` in action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is simple: the definition of `\mycolon` has changed.
In  subfile.tex, it expands to the character `:` (`catcode 12`), while in the main file it expands to the command `:` (`catcode 13`).

This catcode change wouldn't occur when compiling with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX (then `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` must of course be removed).
With these formats, your file compiles as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't for a personal document, but for a LaTeX class of a journal. No hope with PDFLaTeX?